# How to determine if 'would' is simple past or past subjunctive here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense, verbs, modal-verbs

> Andrew McKillop, author of The World’s Final Energy Crisis, calculates that
>
> ✘ (b) China,
>   India and other developing countries will never be able to achieve the vehicle
>   “saturation” ownership levels of the US. ✘
>
> “There is simply no prospect of China,
>   India, Malaysia, Brazil, Turkey, Iran, Ukraine, Mexico and other emerging car producers being able to achieve US, west European, Australian or Japanese rates of
>   car production and ownership,” he says. “At current consumption rates, the
>   estimate of
>
> ✓ 3.5bn motor vehicles **would** increase world oil consumption by about
>   70%.” ✓
>
> In fact, the petrol used to fuel a car is the very end of a massive industrial
>   process that requires oil at every point. Each car requires up to the equivalent of
>   55 barrels of oil, and runs on tyres that are about 40% oil by weight, often on
>   tarmac (oil-based) roads. The real volume of oil needed to equip the world with
>   cars is much higher than expected. “Not only is an explosion of the world car fleet
>   a serious threat to the global environment," McKillop says, “but through its impact
>   on oil demand, it will become a threat to international stability.”

Source: http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2005/jun/30/green.travel (featured in LNAT Sample 1, Passage 7, Q4)

I'm trying to determine which sentence, within ✘ or ✓ , is a fact according to the passage. I had thought that ✘ was a fact, due to the use of the simple future 'will', and the verb 'calculates'. Moreover, I interpreted **would** as a hedge word, expressing doubt/uncertainty. But the answer is ✓. My friend (both our English is basic) claims that **would** is the simple past of 'will.'

But how does this explain my wrong choice? https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21832/50720 doesn't state that **would** is a hedge word. Because [all subjunctives expresses doubt (among other moods)](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/pastsubjunctive.htm) ([About.com for English](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Past-Subjunctive.htm) is too curt), if I'm right that **would** is past subjunctive, then ✓ is NOT a fact?

Answer (score 2):

All the English modals have a wide range of meanings, and *will* has a wider range than most, because it is employed as a marker of temporal posteriority; what meaning is intended in any particular instance must be inferred from context.

In this case, the context is provided **a)** by the future references ***will*** never be able and ***prospect*** of and **b)** by the conditional phrases *at current consumption rates* and *estimate*. *Would* designates the future 70% increase in consumption as the necessary future consequence of extrapolating current rates over the estimated future increase in vehicles. The passage might be paraphrased as a frank conditional:

> If the number of vehicles ***were*** to increase, as estimated, to 3.5bn, this ***would*** increase oil consumption by 70%.

It is a past-tense form expressing a ‘remote’ non-past contingency. It is a ‘fact’ in the sense that the speaker regards the consequence as certain if the conditions are met; it is a ‘non-fact’ in the sense that the speaker regards the consequence—and hence the conditions—as impossible of realization, since realization would be intolerably damaging to the environment and intolerably dangerous to international stability.

Comment: +1 It is a "second conditional":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional

Comment: @CopperKettle If you like to call it that. I don't use that term, since it doesn't reflect anything meaningful about English conditionals.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a rough approximation

Comment: @CopperKettle Thank you. Sadly, the crudity of my English prevents me from understnading some parts of your answer. 1. What is meant by 'temporal posteriority? 2. What is a 'frank conditional? 3. What does 'non-past' mean? Does this differ from 'future'? 4. What's a ‘non-fact’? You also used quots for 'fact', so are you saying that the square isn't a fact?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I wanted to check if you had received my messages above?