# How does 'could' illustrate a fact? Why not use 'can'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, modal-verbs

> [[Para 1:]](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2005/jun/30/green.travel) In 1989, when the environment was briefly top of the UK national agenda, a group
>   of Chinese planners came to London. Many of the people who met them wanted to
>   know how the country had managed to get so many citizens to ride bicycles -
>   something the British authorities were unable to do. The Chinese were perplexed.
>   “You don’t understand”, said one.
>
> ♣ “In 20 years time, no more bicycles. All cars.” ♣ [I purposely spaced these sentences]
>
> *That prediction is being realised.* Beijing’s roads, once kerb-to-kerb with bikes, are
>   now choked with cars. In terms of traffic, noise and air pollution,
>
> ■  Shanghai **could** be Lagos or Cairo. ■

I [still](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/35497/8712) struggle with interpreting English modal verbs. Here, I'm trying to determine which phrase, either that between the clubs or squares, illustrates China’s actual growth in car usage. I had believed in [ODO's Definition 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/could), thus regarded **could** as a hedge word, and finally picked square.

> 1.1. Used to indicate possibility

1. But club is the answer (not square). What did I misread?  If the writer truly wanted the square to be a fact, why not use the more certain **can**? Is definition 1.1 the right match?

2. Also, doesn't '*that prediction is being realised*' support clubs as the answer?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but the short answer to *could* is: because Shanghai **is not** Lagos or Cairo. You are not dealing with a fact. You're dealing with a counterfactual.

Comment: I tried to edit your question to enhance its clarify and visibility on the site, but I don't have sufficient reputation.  In any case, what I was trying to say with my first comment, is the fundamental answer to your question about *could* vs *can* is Shanghai shares some characteristics with Cairo, with Lagos, specifically heavy car traffic and congestion, but it is *not* Cairo. Cairo is in Africa and has pyramids. Shanghai is in Asia and has no pyramids. Cairo has heavy traffic and Shanghai has heavy traffic, so if you squint, you might mistake one for the other, but Shanghai *is not* Cairo.

Comment: @DanBron: Thanks. Would you please post your suggested edit at http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1234/8712 for my viewing?

Comment: I had to discard my edits, so I've lost them. Sorry about that :(

Comment: @DanBron: That's too bad. Would you mind answering 2 as well? Please feel free to answer. I recognise your high standards for posting, but an informal answer will help.

Comment: If clubs were the prediction (stated in 1989), then the Chinese emissary would have been stating an aspiration for Shanghai to *become like* Cairo or Lagos, which seems implausible, to say the least (given the state of Egypt and Nigeria in 1989, given alternative role models like London or Tokyo, given Maoist China's notorious xenophobia...), particularly in contrast to squares, a statement starting with "In 20 years...", which is a literal, textbook, prediction.

Comment: In re: comments vs an answer: I prefer to hang out in the comments, unless the question has a single, definitive, unambiguous answer (which isn't too onerous to find support for from external authorities). Your questions tend to require more interpretive, nuanced, responses, and comments provide a nice discursive format for that. Plus we get to see the full "audit trail" of how we arrived at consensus, which information is (a) kinda important for lit crit and (b) kinda hidden using the answer-editing mechanism.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks again. Sorry, I still don't understand my errors in questions 1 and 2. Would you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

We've had so much rain here lately, this could be India.

That is, in respect to the inordinate amount of rain we're having, we could be in a land that has monsoon season. It is *as if we were* in a monsoon.

Or let's say a news reporter visits New Orleans after Hurricane Katrina:

"There are people without food and water. This could be the Third World."

It is a kind of *exclamation* that involves a statement contrary to fact.   A subjunctive use.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, I still don't understand my errors in questions 1 and 2. Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: Would it be OK to use "might" instead without any change in meaning?  _We've had so much rain here lately, this **might** be India._  _"There are people without food and water. This **might** be the Third World."_ @TRomano

Comment: I won't say that I haven't heard *might* used as a replacement for *could* there, but I've heard *could* far more frequently. One does hear "this might as well be: "They used metal of such low quality in these screws, they might as well be made of plastic!"